# логика кода на opencart 2

Tags: php, post, get, opencart

не могу понять логику кода из opencart 2, ...

```
class Request {
public $get = array();
public $post = array();
public $cookie = array();
public $files = array();
public $server = array();

public function __construct() {
    $this->get = $this->clean($_GET);
    $this->post = $this->clean($_POST);
    $this->request = $this->clean($_REQUEST);
    $this->cookie = $this->clean($_COOKIE);
    $this->files = $this->clean($_FILES);
    $this->server = $this->clean($_SERVER);
}

public function clean($data) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            unset($data[$key]);

            $data[$this->clean($key)] = $this->clean($value);
        }
    } else {
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $data;
}
}
```

а точнее, этот кусок ...

```
public function clean($data) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            unset($data[$key]);

            $data[$this->clean($key)] = $this->clean($value);
        }
    } else {
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется **рекурсивная функция**.

**Смысл:** отфильтровать все элементы находящиеся в массивах, независимо от вложенности массива.

**Условие гласит:** перебирать элементы массива (многомерного массива) до тех пор, пока не будет встречено конечное значение отличное от массива, если значение не является массивом, тогда применить функцию htmlspecialchars к данным.

Представим что есть массив данных:

```
[
   1 => 'test'
   2 => ['test1', 'test2']
]
```

Благодаря этому коду будут обработаны все элементы (test, test1, test2) как значения и не важно сколько массивов будет вложено в друг друга, **ко всем значениям массива будет применена функция htmlspecialchars**.

Comment: Понятно! Спасибо, а в этой части функция вызывает сама себя получается? 
            $data[$this->clean($key)] = $this->clean($value);

Comment: Да, прочитайте про рекурсивные функции, поймете весь смысл. Одно из популярных примеров использования рекурсивных функций - это вычисление чисел фибаноччи.